# SQL INSERT WITHOUT COMMIT

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Я сделал инсерт в таблицу (около 10кк записей) и закрыл курсор не написав коммит.
Перед тем как закрыть курсор, посмотрел размер и объем таблицу, количество строк было 10кк, объем около 950 Мб.
После закрытия курсора, количество строк было 0, но размер таблицы не уменьшился.
Есть ли способ восстановить строки?

Comment: А MySQL тут каким боком? Это MS SQL, он же SQL Server.

Comment: _Есть ли способ восстановить строки?_, а зачем их востанавливать, они же не пропали? Повторите вставку.

Comment: вы строки вставили и удалили из исходной таблицы, или что?

Comment: Если подробно, то в питоне открыл курсор для записи, сделал инсёрт, в свойствах таблицы указывалось загруженное количество строк, потом я закрыл курсор не сделав коммит. Потом таблица была пустая

Comment: Я думаю врядли в журнал пишется информация без commit. Если случайно удалили или проапдейтили - то ещё теоретически восстановить можно, но программы восстановления платные, инфа в журнале шифрованая, мне не удавалось восстановить инфу из журнала.